# php post not able to grap element which append by using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

here is my code, hope you all can understand.
**[html form coding]**

```
<form method='post' action='pro/handle.php'><br/>
    <input type='text' name='FirstTXT' value='First'>
    <button type='button' name='ADDINPUT'>add</button>
    <div id='SETSET'>
        <!-- prepare for adding input element by using jquery -->
    </div>
    <input type='text' name='LastTXT' value='Last'>
    <button type='submit' name='BTN' value='Submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```

**[Jquery coding]**

```
$(document).on("click","[name=ADDINPUT]",function(){
    var inp = "<input type='text' name='ADDTXT'>";
    $("#SETSET").append(inp);
});
```

So far **NO** error/problem for the code above(tested), jquery input did append into #SETSET accordingly.
**[The problem is]**
after click on form [submit] button, php **NOT** able to get the element of [ADDTXT]
when i use php to loop & get everything from previous page, result as below:-
**[PHP coding]**

```
foreach($_post as $key=>$val){
    echo "<br/>$key : $val";
}
```

**[Result]**

```
FirstTXT : First<br/>
LastTXT : Last<br/>
BTN : Submit<br/>
//=== Missing ADDTXT (between First & Last)===//
```

Did you guys/gals know why?

Comment: I think you have to set Inner html of the div not append the value.Use .html() function of Jquery. Please use firebug to check whether your div contains the correct html after clicking

Comment: .html() can continue insert/append? how if i need to add more then 1 input element?

Answer (score 0):

You have an array from that field.

Replace:

```
var inp = "<input type='text' name='ADDTXT'>";
```

With:

```
var inp = "<input type='text' name='ADDTXT[]'>";
```

And PHP:

```
if(is_array($val)) { print_r($val); }
```

OR try:

```
var no = 0;
 $(document).on("click","[name=ADDINPUT]",function(){
++no;
var inp = "<input type='text' name='ADDTXT"+ no +"'>";
$("#SETSET").append(inp);
});
```

Comment: for my real coding, the name will not be same coz everytime i'm add i will put a number behind, ADDTXT1, ADDTXT2, ADDTXT3...., but even having the same name, php should able to grap ADDTXT, but in my case, php did not.

Comment: On my testing envir, it grap ADDTXT but only the last appended input. If i transform into ADDTXT[] it takes all the inputs.

Comment: I edit my answer. Pls test it. When i test, it grap all ADDTXTx fields (only jquery modifications)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that:

html:

```
<form method='post' action='pro/handle.php'><br/>
    <input type='text' name='FirstTXT' value='First'>
    <button type='button' name='ADDINPUT'>add</button>
    <div id='SETSET' style='display: none;'>
        <!-- prepare for adding input element by using jquery -->
        <input type='text' id='ADDTXT' name='ADDTXT' disabled='disabled'>
    </div>
    <input type='text' name='LastTXT' value='Last'>
    <button type='submit' name='BTN' value='Submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```

and JS:

```
$(document).on("click","[name=ADDINPUT]",function(){
    $("#SETSET").show();
    $("#ADDTXT").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: jquery input did show, and still the same after add in your line, thanks by the way